# Prestashop language flag icon looks bad on mobile

Tags: android, ios, icons, prestashop, smartphone

I am facing weird behaviours in prestashop 1.6.0.9. I have enabled Spanish and English on the store. The flags from the language selector look perfect on any pc/mac browser

[image: Spanish selector] Spanish selector

[image: English selector] English selector

but not on smartphones (android or ios)

[image: Mobile language prestashop view]

and I do not know why this is happening.

Any hints??

Comment: i am still confuse this question if related to ios or android and did you used 1x,2xa and 3x image for icons

Comment: All images are full size if is that what you mean

Comment: in ios dev we need to put set of image for supporting retina and non-retina device as par its size

Comment: Yeah but in a 27' thunderbold retina display they look perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone devices have different different resolution and pixel density with each device like following screenshot [image source](http://www.tekrevue.com/retina-display-comparison/):

[image]

Sor for example if you are use one icon let say 50x50 size and its name is btnIcon.png.

for i suggest to use its icon using following size and ppi

```
50x50 with name btnIcon.png and 163ppi
100x100 with name btnIcon@2x.png and 326ppi
150x150 with name btnIcon@3x.png and 401ppi
```

For referance you can check more link for undastand icons size and its setup in ios development:

[Sizes of iPhone UI Elements](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html)

[Designing for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)